# Convert qrcode to Image

Tags: flutter

```
Future<void> _saveQRCodeToGallery() async {
  try {
    final qrImageData = await QrPainter(
      data: widget.qrCodeData,
      version: QrVersions.auto,

    ).toImageData(200);

    if (qrImageData != null) {
      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(qrImageData.buffer.asUint8List()),
        quality: 80,
        name: "qr_code_image",
      );

      if (result['isSuccess']) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text("Image saved to gallery"),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text("Failed to save image to gallery"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error saving image: $e");
  }
}
```

Want to save the generated QR code into gallery in the form of image but the problem is the when i click on save button .The black screen image is saving.

Comment: what are the first 8-12 items of `qrImageData.buffer.asUint8List()` in **hexidecimal** ?

Comment: The qrImageData.buffer.asUint8List() converts the qrImageData into a Uint8List, which represents the binary data of the image.

Comment: is the qr code in svg format or normal image format?

Comment: Normal image format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: I've added margin property at line no. 65. Feel free to modify as per your need.

It is the whole source code, as I commented.

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:developer";
import "dart:io";
import "dart:ui" as ui;

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/services.dart";
import "package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart";
import "package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _saveQRCodeToGallery,
            child: const Text("Tap Here"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _saveQRCodeToGallery() async {
    try {
      final ui.Image image = await QrPainter(
        data: "Hello World!",
        gapless: true,
        version: QrVersions.auto,
        color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.white : null,
        emptyColor: Colors.white,
      ).toImage(1000);
      final ByteData qrImageData = await CodePainter(
            qrImage: image,
            margin: 50,
          ).toImageData(1000) ??
          ByteData(0);

      if (qrImageData.lengthInBytes > 0) {
        final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
          Uint8List.fromList(qrImageData.buffer.asUint8List()),
          quality: 100,
          name: "generated_qr_code_${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}",
        );
        if (mounted) {
          final String message = result["isSuccess"] ? "Success" : "Failure";
          final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else {}
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      log("Exception caught: $e");
    }
  }
}

class CodePainter extends CustomPainter {
  CodePainter({required this.qrImage, this.margin = 10}) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.fill;
  }
  final double margin;
  final ui.Image qrImage;
  late Paint _paint;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Rect rect = Rect.fromPoints(
      Offset.zero,
      Offset(size.width, size.height),
    );
    canvas
      ..drawRect(rect, _paint)
      ..drawImage(qrImage, Offset(margin, margin), Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  ui.Picture toPicture(double size) {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    paint(canvas, Size(size, size));
    return recorder.endRecording();
  }

  Future<ui.Image> toImage(
    double size, {
    ui.ImageByteFormat format = ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
  }) async {
    return Future<ui.Image>.value(
      toPicture(size).toImage(size.toInt(), size.toInt()),
    );
  }

  Future<ByteData?> toImageData(
    double originalSize, {
    ui.ImageByteFormat format = ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
  }) async {
    final ui.Image image = await toImage(
      originalSize + margin * 2,
      format: format,
    );
    return image.toByteData(format: format);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try & test this above source code.

Comment: full qr code image is not saving into the gallery it will cut the border as a result when i select this qr code from gallery to generate result in the form of text it will not show. Also this code saved the same qr code into gallery.

Comment: Generated QR:
https://i.postimg.cc/qM0wvz4C/Screenshot-1693901092.png

Scanned QR:
https://i.postimg.cc/sg5396bL/ac2a8a0e-5631-4756-bacc-c46d1b17cf03.jpg

Comment: I used Google Lens to scan the QR.

Comment: if i want to show the qr code image like this :https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=562654342&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK1061PK1061&sxsrf=AB5stBhG0g8FaST0Yzg7Jc6F5mufhG3tBg:1693887575208&q=qr+code&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFttb5zpKBAxWFVqQEHZguCtUQ0pQJegQIDBAB&cshid=1693887575759949&biw=1920&bih=963&dpr=1#imgrc=rjzpwZotUfeNJM what should i do?

Comment: It depends on what you pass in the data.

Comment: i mean like full qr code show in the center and some white color padding around the qr

Comment: I've added margin property at line no. 65. Feel free to modify as per your need.

Comment: Kindly refresh this page so you get the updated answer.

Comment: Feel free to provide feedback.

Comment: color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.black : null,
        emptyColor: Colors.white,
    in this the color should be black.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line below `version: QrVersions.auto`,

```
color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.white : null,
```

I tested on Android emulator & iOS simulator. It's working as expected.

So, it's going to look like this:

```
final qrImageData = await QrPainter(
  data: widget.qrCodeData,
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  color: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.white : null,
).toImageData(200);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your instructions and the image is saved in to the gallery but now the problem is ,image is not in clear pixels

Comment: Replace toImageData(200) with toImageData(1000).

Comment: Let me share the whole source code.

Comment: when i regenerated the qr code and press save button the new generated qr code is not saving .

Comment: full qr code image is not saving into the gallery it will cut the border as a result when i select this qr code from gallery to generate result in the form of text it will not show

Comment: Try & test my other answer.

Comment: I've added margin property at line no. 65. Feel free to modify as per your need.

Comment: Kindly refresh this page so you get the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the colour-related properties for the QR widget

```
 final qrImageData = await QrPainter(
        data: widget.qrCodeData,
        version: QrVersions.auto,
        color: Colors.black, // Set the QR code color to black
        emptyColor: Colors.white, // Set the background color to white
      ).toImageData(200);
```